# How do I remove unwanted Transform Orientations?

Tags: transforms

I'm using a lot of custom-defined transform orientations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) recently while modeling. The list has grown too large, how do I remove some or all of them?

[image: Transform orientations]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The custom transforms are also listed in the 'Transform Orientations' panel in the Properties shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>).

Choose the custom transform you would like to delete from the list, then press the 'x' next to it to remove it:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to delete a transform orientations by selecting it, hitting <kbd>Space</kbd>, and searching for *Delete Orientation*.